# WPF: Use PropertyGrid from WPF Extended

Tags: wpf, dll, namespaces, propertygrid

I'm new in WPF (.NET 4.0, VS2010) and try to include a property grid. My XAML Markup looks like the following:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfToolkit="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WpfToolkit:PropertyGrid Name="Grid" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I get the error that the assembly 'WPFToolkit.Extended' was not found. I have included the reference to the dll Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll in my application.

Why does it not work? Have I to include more references or what can be the mistake?
Thanks for any Response.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the assembly in the property menu? I.e. right click References > Add new reference?

Comment: Yes, the assembly is referenced in the property menu. Therefore I can't unterstand why this error is shown.

Comment: I have had this before with one of my own classes. To fix it I think I re-added the reference, cleaned the solution and rebuilt all.

Comment: Sadly, after this there is still the same result.

Comment: In the code behind the PropertyGrid can be accessed like **Dim propertyGrid As Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid**. The error from above seems to be only at markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem. My fault was that I had not unblocked the zip file containing the dll. After this I have to change the source for the namespace in the Markup to an uri. Below the final markup:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WpfToolkit:PropertyGrid Name="Grid" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your project properties.  Under application, what is selected under target framework?  By default with a new project, '.Net Framework 4 Client Profile' is selected.  If the extended library uses parts of .net that beyond the client profile, you will need to select '.Net Framekwork 4' instead to use the extended functionality.

Comment: This was the first Setting I made after creating the project ;-)